# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on jenkins homepage

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, centos7

I am trying to install jenkins on AWS CENTOS7 EC2 instance.
i have performed below mentioned steps :

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
curl --silent --location http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo | 
sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key
sudo yum install jenkins
sudo systemctl start jenkins
systemctl status jenkins
```

`systemctl status jenkins` shows following output :

[image]

I have also tried disabling firewall :

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
```

Also, following security groups are added to my instance :

[image]

Still i am facing **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT** on trying to access jenkins homepage with following command :

```
http://Client_PublicIP:8080/jenkins
```

Please help and let me know if i am missing on something else.

Comment: Why are you using /jenkins? Could you tr try with `http://Client_PublicIP:8080, http://Client_PublicIP:80 http://Client_PublicIP` Also when you create an ec2 instance, you get automatically a public domain something like ec2-56-78-43-west2.compute.amazonaws.com. Could you try with that domain?

Comment: Apache page is accessible using just Client_PublicIP or ec2-public-domain,com.
But when i am using it with port 8080, its not accessibe.

Comment: After adding custom TCP rule in EC2 security group, i am able to get Jenkins page and enter admin pwd. But post entering admin password and clicking on Continue, I am facing below error - 
    HTTP ERROR 404
    Problem accessing /Jenkins. Reason : Not Found
    Powered by Jetty://9.4.z-SNAPSHOT